# When I ran `bundle exec rake test:prepare` it errored out, but `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` goes through fine with warning. What's going on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156936/rails-rake-dbtestprepare-vs-rake-testprepare) one is a shortcut wrapper (so I'm guessing they're the same).

When I ran `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`, I get this error:

```
Don't know how to build task 'test:prepare'
/Users/aj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/aj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

...but when I ran `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` , I get this warning:

```
WARNING: db:test:prepare is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically, see the release notes for details.
```

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: I think the error should instead suggest the syntax @Logan Serman mentioned. It's presumptuous to assume anyone's test/spec helper would have the "updated" syntax.

Answer (score 50):

In Rails 4.1+, they deprecated db:test:prepare with that message. You can now just use:

`ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`

in spec_helper.rb (or similar files if you're not using RSpec). That will automatically keep your test database in sync with your schema. Because of this 'automatic' method, db:test:prepare is no longer needed in most cases.

If you need to do it manually for some reason, you can still use

`rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: Spring definitely has some issues, but I've been using Rails 4.1 every day since beta and never had a problem using `maintain_test_schema!` and Spring.

Comment: A potential gotcha `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` fails to work correctly when a migration is added, tests are run, then `rake db:rollback` is used, then the migration is changed. It then thinks the schema is up to date when it's not.

Comment: Running Rails 4.1.0, couldn't get it to work -- had an `UninitializedConstant` error for ActiveRecord.  Not sure what happened.

Comment: Here's a nice [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade) from RSpec.

Comment: @JamieD is this a noted bug in the ActiveRecord repo?