# Rails 4 - rspec test dont pass for Polymorphic Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I trying to test a polymorphic association.

I am using RSpec 3.0.2 and shoulda-matchers 2.6.2. My Rails version is: 4.1.4 and Ruby 2.1.2

My First Model: app/models/address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

My Second Model: app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
end
```

My third model: app/models/company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
end
```

For Address table, I have this migration:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :addresses do |t|
            t.string :description
            t.references :addressable, polymorphic: true
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

And for my first specification, I have: spec/models/address_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Address, :type => :model do
    it { should belong_to :addressable }
end
```

But when I try to run the specification I have this error:

> Failures:
>
> 1) Address should belong to addressable
>        Failure/Error: it { should belong_to :addressable }
>          Expected Address to have a belongs_to association called addressable (Address does not have a addressable_id foreign key.)
>        # ./spec/models/address_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in '

[image]

Generated table by migration:

[image]

Can You please help me identifying where I am missing. I just looked from google coming to stackoverflow, but not solution.

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable, searchable, or accessible.

Comment: I got it . Post updated 

Thanks @AndrewMarshall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addressable_id` column is not in your test database. Run:

```
bundle exec rake db:test:clone
```

to sync your database changes to your test database.

Comment: Thanks.. it works... you saved my day.

But running this command I get this warning:

`WARNING: db:test:clone is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically, see the release notes for details.`

Comment: @PSantos, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351783/when-i-ran-bundle-exec-rake-testprepare-it-errored-out-but-bundle-exec-rake will show you how to update your spec_helper so that Rails will maintain your test schema.

Comment: Hi @infused, this does not help because in my spec/rails_helper.rb (generated by rails g rspec:install) I just have this line:


`ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`

But the schema was not updated automatically

Comment: @PSantos, you should open a separate question about `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` not working.