# Rails 4: db:test:prepare says it is deprecated, yet tests don't work without it

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I'm using Rails 4.1.4. Whenever I run new migrations, my tests fail, because the migration is apparently not applied to the test database. In the past, I had to run the `db:test:prepare` rake task, but that now says it's deprecated (though it still works).

My question is, what do I have to do, so the test schema is maintained automatically, as the deprecation message now falsely claims?

Some additional info that might be relevant:

- I started developing my app on Rails 3.x, then upgraded to 4.x. Maybe this problem does not occur in clean 4.x installs?
- I'm using the `:sql` schema format (`config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`), because I need some db features not supported by the `:ruby` format. Maybe the automatic test migrations work only with the `:ruby` format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I ran \`bundle exec rake test:prepare\` it errored out, but \`bundle exec rake db:test:prepare\` goes through fine with warning. What's going on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351783/when-i-ran-bundle-exec-rake-testprepare-it-errored-out-but-bundle-exec-rake)

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth: It is not duplicate, I'm asking different thing. The answer over there, however, seems to be helpful for me too.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I just mean that the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
rake test:prepare
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```